# Get ids from DB in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Can I simplify this code without foreach?

```
$userQuestIds = [2,4,45,586,16,2,143,234,654,78,56];

$typeQuests = [];
foreach ($userQuestIds as $qId) {
    $typeQuests[] = Quest::where(['id' => $qId])->first();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is a primary key the shortest way is:

```
$typeQuests = Quest::find($userQuestIds);
```

Comment: This is the simplest and best way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses:%7E:text=whereNotIn%20/%20orWhereIn%20/%20orWhereNotIn-,The,that%20a%20given%20column%27s%20value%20is%20contained%20within%20the%20given%20array%3A,-%24users%20%3D%20DB):

```
$typeQuests = Quest::whereIn('id', $userQuestIds)->get();
```

NOTE: this approach is better for columns other than `id` (as primary). I think @andriy-Lozynskiy solution is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `whereIn()` method on the `QueryBuilder` class

```
$userQuestIds = [2,4,45,586,16,2,143,234,654,78,56];
$typeQuests = Quest::whereIn('id', $userQuestIds)->get();
```